# Browser cache and cookie transsfer

Tags: cookies, browser-cache

How to transfer cache and cookie of Firefox browser to opera browser?
I have tried different method but can't find a way out?

Comment: can you provide which methods have you tried ? As if we post same methods for you, that you had already done than there is no used of that !

Answer (score -1):

Firefox saves all browsing history, cache and all in `places.sqlite` and opera saves in `download.dat`. So you just have to the copy `places.sqlite` from Firefox and paste or drag&drop to the folder where `download.dat` resides.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Can Opera read an sqlite file?

Comment: I can't find places.sqlite